# Powershell Gui not releasing form Data entered into textboxes

Tags: forms, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell form that pulls active directory information. 1 section get the account name from entering the First and Last Names into textboxes. after the results are displayed and I attempt to find another username I get the same results as the previous search or I get an error. Is there a line of code I need to clear the cache so to speak.

```
<# 
.NAME
    AD Account Tool
.SYNOPSIS
    Check User by SamAccountName . Can Unlock User and lock user. Reset Password, enable nad disable user
.DESCRIPTION
    Checks user by SamAccountName. Returns Name, Last LogonDate, LockedOut Status, LockedoutTime, and Enabled Status. Allows User to be unlocked and locked. Locking of user is by increasing badpasswordcount. User is able to reset password for account. Enabling and disabling of Users are allowed.
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$fname= $FirstName.Text
$lname= $LastName.Text

$CheckLockTool                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$CheckLockTool.ClientSize        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(700,200)
$CheckLockTool.text              = "User Account Administration Tool"
$CheckLockTool.TopMost           = $false

$CheckLocked                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckLocked.text                = "Check Locked"
$CheckLocked.width               = 100
$CheckLocked.height              = 30
$CheckLocked.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,60)
$CheckLocked.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$CheckGroups                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$CheckGroups.text                = "Check Groups"
$CheckGroups.width               = 100
$CheckGroups.height              = 30
$CheckGroups.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,89)
$CheckGroups.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$FirstName                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$FirstName.Text                  = ""
$FirstName.multiline             = $false
$FirstName.width                 = 100
$FirstName.height                = 20
$FirstName.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$FirstName.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Lbl_FirstName                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Lbl_FirstName.text              = "First Name"
$Lbl_FirstName.AutoSize          = $true
$Lbl_FirstName.width             = 25
$Lbl_FirstName.height            = 10
$Lbl_FirstName.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$Lbl_FirstName.Font              = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$LastName                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$LastName.Text                   = ""
$LastName.multiline              = $false
$LastName.width                  = 100
$LastName.height                 = 20
$LastName.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,30)
$LastName.Font                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Lbl_LastName                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Lbl_LastName.text               = "Last Name"
$Lbl_LastName.AutoSize           = $true
$Lbl_LastName.width              = 25
$Lbl_LastName.height             = 10
$Lbl_LastName.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,10)
$Lbl_LastName.Font               = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$User                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$User.Text                       = ""
$User.multiline                  = $false
$User.width                      = 174
$User.height                     = 25
$User.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,96)
$User.Font                       = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Header                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Header.text                     = "Enter Users 6+2"
$Header.AutoSize                 = $true
$Header.width                    = 25
$Header.height                   = 10
$Header.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,76)
$Header.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$UnlockAccount                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$UnlockAccount.text              = "Unlock Account"
$UnlockAccount.width             = 100
$UnlockAccount.height            = 30
$UnlockAccount.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,60)
$UnlockAccount.Font              = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$LockAccount                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$LockAccount.text                = "Lock Account"
$LockAccount.width               = 100
$LockAccount.height              = 30
$LockAccount.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,89)
$LockAccount.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$LastLogon                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$LastLogon.text                  = "Last Logon"
$LastLogon.width                 = 100
$LastLogon.height                = 30
$LastLogon.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(425,89)
$LastLogon.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$Header2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Header2.text                    = "Set New Password"
$Header2.AutoSize                = $true
$Header2.width                   = 25
$Header2.height                  = 10
$Header2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(14,137)
$Header2.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Password                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Password.multiline              = $false
$Password.width                  = 174
$Password.height                 = 20
$Password.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,159)
$Password.Font                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$SetPassword                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$SetPassword.text                = "Set Password"
$SetPassword.width               = 100
$SetPassword.height              = 30
$SetPassword.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,150)
$SetPassword.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$DIsableAccount                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$DIsableAccount.text             = "Disable Account"
$DIsableAccount.width            = 100
$DIsableAccount.height           = 30
$DIsableAccount.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,150)
$DIsableAccount.Font             = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$EnableAccount                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$EnableAccount.text              = "Enable Account"
$EnableAccount.width             = 100
$EnableAccount.height            = 30
$EnableAccount.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(420,150)
$EnableAccount.Font              = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8)

$getacctname                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$getacctname.text                = "Get 6+2"
$getacctname.width               = 100
$getacctname.height              = 30
$getacctname.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,25)
$getacctname.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)


$CheckLockTool.controls.AddRange(@($Lbl_FirstName,$Lbl_LastName,$FirstName,$LastName,$getacctname,$LastLogon,$CheckGroups,$CheckLocked,$User,$Header,$UnlockAccount,$LockAccount,$Header2,$Password,$SetPassword,$DIsableAccount,$EnableAccount))

$CheckLocked.Add_Click({ CheckLocked })
$CheckGroups.Add_Click({ CheckGroups })
$UnlockAccount.Add_Click({ UnlockAccount })
$LockAccount.Add_Click({ LockAccount })
$SetPassword.Add_Click({ SetPassword })
$DIsableAccount.Add_Click({ DisableAccount })
$EnableAccount.Add_Click({ EnableAccount })
$LastLogon.Add_Click({ LastLogon })
$getacctname.Add_Click({getacctname})

#region Logic 

#Write your logic code here
function SetPassword { 
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User.text -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password.text -Force)
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Password Changed')
}

function CheckLocked {

$Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
$Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Locked Accounts'

    
}

function CheckGroups {

$Result = Get-ADUser –Identity $User.text -Properties Name, Memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
$Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Group Memberships'

    
}

function LastLogon {

$Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate| Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate 
$Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Last Logon'

    
}

function getacctname {

$Result = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$fname' -and SurName -eq '$lname'"| Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'SamAccountName' 
$Result | Out-Gridview -Title 'Windows Logon'

    
}


function UnlockAccount { 
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $User.text
    
    $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Unlocked Account'
}

function LockAccount { 
if ($LockoutBadCount = ((([xml](Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType Xml)).GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.Account |
            Where-Object name -eq LockoutBadCount).SettingNumber)) {
 
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'NotMyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force
 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, LockedOut |
        ForEach-Object {
 
            for ($i = 1; $i -le $LockoutBadCount; $i++) { 
 
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName dc01 {Get-Process
                } -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($($_.UserPrincipalName), $Password)) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue            
 
            }
 
            $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
            $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Unlocked Account'
        }
}
}

function EnableAccount {
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $User.text
    $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Enabled Account'
    }


function DisableAccount { 
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $User.text
    $Result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.text -Properties Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled | select Name, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, AccountLockOutTime, Enabled 
    $Result | Out-GridView -Title 'Disabled Account'
}


# Disable other types of close/exit
#$form.add_FormClosing({$_.Cancel=$true})


#Write-Output
#endregion

[void]$CheckLockTool.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had a malfunction in a function.
the correct function is below.

```
function getacctname {
    $fname= $FirstName.Text
    $lname= $LastName.Text
    $Result = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$fname' -and SurName -eq '$lname'"| Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'SamAccountName' 
    $Result | Out-Gridview -Title 'Windows Logon'
}
```